# No intellisense on Visual Studio Live Share as a guest

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense, visual-studio-liveshare

So, I've been helping a friend of mine debug some C# (Windows Forms, .NET 5) code for some college work through Live Share.

Both of us are using the most up to date version of Visual Studio 2019 and have the most recent version of the Live Share extension.

The problem is, when I enter his codebase, I cannot see Intellisense, no autocomplete, no red squiggly lines to show errors. Nothing. All I get is the solution error report at the bottom of the screen.

I also got this error when joining the session:

> The Output Channel Consumer is operating with reduced functionality due to the absence of a dependency service: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OutputChannelStore (0.1).

Does anyone know how to solve this?